# Site em PHP está fazendo download

Tags: nginx

Estava tentando configurar o serverblocks (vhost) do nginx, então eu apaguei o arquivo "default" localizado em `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` e criei um arquivo com o nome do meu site, adicionei essas linhas abaixo:

```
 server {
    listen   80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name http://localhost/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

E agora o meu site que é em PHP, testado no meu servidor, quando abro, ele faz o download! Acho que alguma linha de código que estava no arquivo "default" tinha algo de interpretar códigos PHP?

Como recuperar essa configuração?

Comment: Acho que é só colocar `location` dentro de `server`.

Comment: Não resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Assim como o Vinícius comentou, a propriedade *location* fica dentro de *server*. Como respondido [nessa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26668444/1432957) do SOen,

1. Altere seu código para:

   ```
   server {
       listen   80;
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;

       # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
       server_name localhost;

       location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Edite o /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini e definia o valor de *cgi.fix_pathinfo* para *0*.
3. Reinicie o nginx e o php5.